# After String.format() with a value read from a file the resulting string does not contain the part after the inserted value

Tags: python, string.format

I have a script that uses SSH via Paramiko to login to switches and initiate a TFTP copy of the startup-config. This almost works like I want except the file name does not include the .txt file type.

The specific line I'm working with is:

```
command.send("copy startup-config tftp://192.168.0.1/Backup-{}.txt \n".format(i))
```

Tried looking at examples on Google.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
###############################################
# THIS SCRIPT SAVES THE RUNNING-CONFIG TO     #
# STARTUP-CONFIG AND THEN COPIES THE          #
# STARTUP-CONFIG TO THE SPECIFIED IP VIA TFTP # 
###############################################
#
import paramiko
import sys, time
#
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'
#
with open('Advantech_Test_IPs', 'r') as host_list:
    for i in host_list:
        str(i)
        try:
            ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh_client.connect(i, username=username, password=password)
            command = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
            command.send("copy running-config startup-config \n")
            time.sleep(1)
            command.send("copy startup-config tftp://.../Backup-{}.txt \n".format(i))
            time.sleep(1)
            ssh_client.close
            print(i, "BACKUP COMPLETE")
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError as e:
            pass
            print(i, "No Valid Connections")
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException as ea:
            print(i, "Authentication Failed")
        except paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException as eb:
            print(i, "Bad Host Key")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(i, "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!")
print("All done.")
```

The file gets copied over, but the .txt file extension is not appended so I end up with file types that match the last part of the IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` contains a new line at the end. So effectively you are sending a two lines to the server:

```
copy startup-config tftp://192.168.0.1/Backup-IP
.txt
```

You can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (or [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)) to remove the newline:

```
command.send("copy startup-config tftp://192.168.0.1/Backup-{}.txt \n".format(i.strip()))
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Just for my own understanding, where is the newline after i? Is it just automatically there?

Comment: Your file contains `"IP1\nIP2\nIP3\n..."` – When you iterate it line-by-line, you get `"IP1\n"`, `"IP2\n"`, `"IP3\n"`...